# Simplest possible sample to connect selfhosted signalR-server and client?

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm trying to connect a client to a self-hosted SignalR-server.

My server looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
        var server = new Server(url);

        server.MapConnection<MyConnection>("/echo");

        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection
    {
    }
```

It was the simplest I could came up with. And the client looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SignalR.Client.Connection conn = new SignalR.Client.Connection("http://localhost:8081/echo");
        Task start = conn.Start();
        start.Wait();

        if (start.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I can't get the code above to work. The server start, but when I run the client code to connect I got an error:

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

And the server is also giving me an error: Cannot access a disposed object.

Have I forgot something? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
The error I get on the server is the following....

SignalRtest.vshost.exe Error: 0 : A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
SignalR exception thrown by Task: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListenerResponse'.
   at System.Net.HttpListenerResponse.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.HttpListenerResponse.get_OutputStream()
   at SignalR.Hosting.Self.Infrastructure.ResponseExtensions.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Action`1 endMethod, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListenerResponse'.
   at System.Net.HttpListenerResponse.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.HttpListenerResponse.get_OutputStream()
   at SignalR.Hosting.Self.Infrastructure.ResponseExtensions.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Action`1 endMethod, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)<---

'client.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll'

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this?  I am experiencing the exact same thing.

Comment: No, but after installing vs11 and running in debugmode the code above runs.....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's disposing the server variable because it doesn't see it being used later in the function. Add GC.KeepAlive( server ) to the end of your Main function to make sure it doesn't get disposed of early. Or better yet, but it in a using statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not right. This sample code should work just fine. But it does nothing. I'd suggest debugging to find out what the 500 actually is.

Comment: I dont have VS11 installed so I cant debug the project, but I've added the errorlog I get on the serverside.

Comment: I've installed VS11 now och cloned the SignalR repository. If I run the same code in debug-mode and in VS11...it works!!!